# Linear Algebra Proof: Invertible matrices, construction of the field on complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, proof-writing

Let $x$, $y$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ and let 
$Z = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    x       & -y \\
    y       &  x
\end{bmatrix}$.

Prove that $Z$ is invertible if and only if $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$.

---

I believe that this is constructing a field over the field of complex numbers, but I am struggling to do so. Does anyone have any recommendations or way forward?

Comment: There is an ismorphism from the matrices in the from of $Z$  to the the complex numbers $(x+iy)$  And, you could prove that, and ultimately will want to prove that.  But, that is really not necessary to prove the proposition above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A $2\times2$ matrix is invertible if and only if it's *determinant* is not 0. This matrix has the determinant $x^2 + y^2$, which is $0$ if and only if both $x$ and $y$ are zero. Therefore it is invertible if and only if $x \neq 0$ **or** $y \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=y=0$, then $Z$ is the null matrix, which is not invertible.

Otherwise, the matrix$\begin{bmatrix}\frac x{x^2+y^2}&\frac y{x^2+y^2}\\\frac {-y}{x^2+y^2}&\frac x{x^2+y^2}\end{bmatrix}$ is the inverse of $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Another perspective:
$$
\mathbf{A}^{-1} = 
 \left[ \begin{array}{cr}
 x & -y \\ y & x
 \end{array} \right]^{-1} = \frac{\text{adj}\mathbf{A}}{\det \mathbf{A}}=
\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}  
 \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
 -x & y \\ -y & -x
 \end{array} \right]
$$
When does the inverse not exist? When $x^{2}+y^{2} = 0$.